# Glossaries Acronyms Not Displaying issue

Tags: miktex, glossaries, acronyms, texworks

I am going absolutely insane trying to create a simple list of acronyms for my dissertation and was wondering if anyone can shed some light on my issue. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and texworks. I followed the following guide to create a glossary with acronyms as seen below

```
\documentclass{article}

% Load hyperref before glossaries
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

% Define a new glossary type
\newglossary[slg]{symbols}{sym}{sbl}{List of Symbols}

\makeglossaries

% The following definitions will go in the main glossary

\newglossaryentry{culdesac}{name=cul-de-sac,description={passage
or street closed at one end},plural=culs-de-sac}

\newglossaryentry{elite}{name={\'e}lite,description={select
group or class},sort=elite}

\newglossaryentry{elitism}{name={\'e}litism,description={advocacy
of dominance by an \gls{elite}},sort=elitism}

\newglossaryentry{attache}{name=attach\'e,
description={person with special diplomatic responsibilities}}

% The following definitions will go in the list of acronyms
% Acronym definitions
\newacronym{uri}{URI}{Unique Resonance Identifier}

\newacronym{led}{LED}{light-emitting diode}

\newacronym{eeprom}{EEPROM}{electrically TESTICLE programmable
read-only memory}

% The following definitions will go in the list of symbols

\newglossaryentry{ohm}{type=symbols,name=ohm,
symbol={\ensuremath{\Omega}},
description=unit of electrical resistance}

\newglossaryentry{angstrom}{type=symbols,name={\aa}ngstr\"om,
symbol={\AA},sort=angstrom,
description={non-SI unit of length}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Diplomatic Memoirs}

When I was an \gls{attache}, I lived in a \gls{culdesac}, but
I didn't much care for it as I found there was a fair amount
of \gls{elitism} amongst my neighbours.

\section{Student Memoirs}

When I was a student I often left bits of electronic circuitry
in my pockets, such as \glspl{led} and \glspl{eeprom}, which
often ended up in the washing machine. The \glspl{led} didn't
fair too badly, but the \glspl{eeprom} frequently broke.

\section{Symbols}

The \gls{angstrom} is commonly used in structural biology,
whereas the \gls{ohm} is used in electronics.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I have perl installed and already went into the preferences and added a typset for makeglossaries. If I run the code I get a document displayed as followed:
[image: output]

however I cannot add in ANY of my own acronyms using the following line:

```
\newacronym{URI}{URI}{Unique Resonance Identifier}
```

I can only edit the EEPROM and LED acronyms for some reason even after re-running makeglossaries.

I know this must be something stupid and any help would be much appreciated ideally I just want a page of a simple list of acronyms :(

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! By default only acronyms actually used in the text is added to the list. If you use another acronym and recompile, does that appear as well?

Comment: your right - It does is there anyway to display them even if they are not used within the text, I have already written sections that use the abbreviations for example I don't want to have to go through the text and use gls\ everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour is to only add to the list of acronyms those that are actually used in the text. If you want to add all defined acronyms to the list of acronyms, use `\glsaddall[types=\acronymtype]`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{uri}{URI}{Unique Resonance Identifier}
\newacronym{led}{LED}{light-emitting diode}
\newacronym{eeprom}{EEPROM}{electrically TESTICLE programmable
read-only memory}

\glsaddall[types=\acronymtype]
\begin{document}
No acronyms here.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will give it a shot thanks and will accept if it works as soon as possible